# How can you select unique objects based on two properties of an object in powershell?

Tags: powershell, object, properties, unique

I have an array of Objects that have 6 properties. That look like this:

```
$csvData
CURRENT DATE AND TIME : 07/10/2015 08:17:17 CST
USER NAME             : userName
COMPUTER NAME         : computerName
IP ADDRESS            : 192.168.1.1
LOGON SERVER          : logonServer
LOGON/OFF             : logon
```

I want to create an array of objects where username and computer name are not duplicated. How can I get only the unique username/computername combo in powershell? Ultimately I would like to remove all duplicates and add a property 'Count' that keeps track of how many duplicates there are.

I have tried:

```
$csvDataUnique = $csvData | Select-Object 'User Name','Computer Name' -Unique
$csvDataUnique = $csvData | sort -Property 'User Name' | Get-Unique
```

Comment: I have also tried:


   `$csvData = $csvData.GetEnumerator() | %{$_.'User Name',$_.'Computer Name'} | Select-Object -Unique`

Answer (score 24):

Very similar to Mathias' answer, but will have all of the columns in the output:

```
$csvDataUnique = $csvData | 
  Group-Object 'User Name','Computer Name' | 
  %{ $_.Group | Select 'User Name','Computer Name' -First 1} | 
  Sort 'User Name','Computer Name'
```

Answer (score 6):

The other answers didn't retain the rest of the properties in the final output. This should work for you:

```
$csvDataUnique = $csvData | Group-Object -Property 'User Name', 'Computer Name' | ForEach-Object { $_.Group[0] }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom property with your `Select-Object`. So you were pretty close already. Try this:

```
Select-Object @{Label = "Index"; Expression = {"$($_.'User Name') $($_.'Computer Name')"} } -Unique
```

It basically combines the two fields into a single string and sorts unique on that. I called the field "Index" but it could be called anything.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative option is to use `Get-Unique`.
It was quite helpful in my situation when I wanted to select objects based on a unique property without some extensive foreach-loop.

`$csvData | Sort-Object 'User Name', 'Computer Name' | Get-Unique -AsString`

The object needs to be sorted because `Get-Unique` compares the strings adjacent to each other. Additionally, the comparison is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I usually resort to using a hash table, and joined property values for the keys for that kind of task:

```
$CSVDataUnique = @{}

$csvData | foreach {
 $CSVDataUnique["$_.'User Name'\$_.'Computer Name'"]++
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Group-Object` to group by multiple properties:

```
$Uniqs = $csvData | Group -Property "USER NAME","COMPUTER NAME" -NoElement | Select -Expand Name
```