# Select unique objects based on four properties of an object in Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is a follow-up to the following thread:

[How can you select unique objects based on two properties of an object in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343752/how-can-you-select-unique-objects-based-on-two-properties-of-an-object-in-powers)

I have a csv with about 20 headers.
I want to sort uniquely on about 4 of them, but then ensure the remaining 16 headers are kept.

To simplify, I'll pretend there are only eight headers:

```
Host                           : ComputerA
IPv4 Address                   : 1.1.1.2
MAC Address                    : abcdef123456
Switch IP                      : 1.1.1.1
NIC Vendor                     : Dell
Device Type:                   : Workstation
Location                       : Office A
Comment:                       : Computer of CFO
```

The proposed, adapted solution, found in the linked thread, is not working for me.

For reference:

```
$csvDataUnique = $csvData | 
  Group-Object 'User Name','Computer Name' | 
  %{ $_.Group | Select 'User Name','Computer Name' -First 1} | 
  Sort 'User Name','Computer Name'
```

For my scenario, I want to match on Host, IPv4 Address, MAC Address, and Switch IP, so I am trying the following commands:

```
$csvData = import-csv mydata.csv
$csvDataUnique = $csvData | 
  Group-Object 'Host', 'IPv4  Address', 'MAC Address', 'Switch IP' | 
  %{ $_.Group | Select 'Host', 'IPv4  Address', 'MAC Address', 'Switch IP' -First 1} | 
  Sort 'Host', 'IPv4  Address', 'MAC Address', 'Switch IP'
$csvDataUnique | export-csv "SortedData.csv"
```

When I attempt this, it only outputs the four selected headers. As stated previously, I'm looking to also keep the headers as well.

Again, for reference:

Input:

```
Host                           : ComputerA
IPv4 Address                   : 1.1.1.2
MAC Address                    : abcdef123455
Switch IP                      : 1.1.1.1
NIC Vendor                     : Dell
Device Type:                   : Workstation
Location                       : Office A
Comment:                       : Computer of CFO

Host                           : ComputerA
IPv4 Address                   : 1.1.1.2
MAC Address                    : abcdef123455
Switch IP                      : 1.1.1.1
NIC Vendor                     : Dell
Device Type:                   : Workstation
Location                       : Office A
Comment:                       :

Host                           : ComputerB
IPv4 Address                   : 1.1.1.3
MAC Address                    : abcdef123456
Switch IP                      : 1.1.1.1
NIC Vendor                     : Dell
Device Type:                   : Workstation
Location                       : Office A
Comment:                       :

Host                           : ComputerB
IPv4 Address                   : 1.1.1.3
MAC Address                    : abcdef123456
Switch IP                      : 1.1.1.1
NIC Vendor                     : Dell
Device Type:                   : Workstation
Location                       : Office A
Comment:                       :
```

Desired output:

```
Host                           : ComputerA
IPv4 Address                   : 1.1.1.2
MAC Address                    : abcdef123455
Switch IP                      : 1.1.1.1
NIC Vendor                     : Dell
Device Type:                   : Workstation
Location                       : Office A
Comment:                       : Computer of CFO

Host                           : ComputerB
IPv4 Address                   : 1.1.1.3
MAC Address                    : abcdef123456
Switch IP                      : 1.1.1.1
NIC Vendor                     : Dell
Device Type:                   : Workstation
Location                       : Office A
Comment:                       :
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean _columns_, not _headers_.

Comment: If you group by 4 properties (columns), but want _all_ properties in the output, you need to decide _which particular object_ from each group you want; `-First 1` picks the first one; if you want that first object with all its properties, simply omit the list of property names from the `Select-Object` (`Select`) call: `%{ $_.Group | Select  -First 1}` or, more succinctly and efficiently: `%{ $_.Group[0] }`

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, I do want the the first value. I'll try this and get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Join-object module
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join-Object/2.0.1

This will allow you to merge the data.